# access nested associative array in smarty template

Tags: php, templates, smarty, prestashop

I have a php array named `consolidatedReviewData`, which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [consolidatedData] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [a_productidentification] => 5920
                    [avg_rating] => 4.0000
                    [no_reviews] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

and I am assigning it to a smarty variable like this:

```
self::$smarty->assign('cosolidatedReviews', $consolidatedReviewData);
```

Now, my question is how do I directly access `avg_rating` inside the .tpl?

Something like:

```
{$consolidatedReviewData->consolidatedData->0->avg_rating}
```

Comment: you cant access _avg_rating_ directly ,you need to loop through `$consolidatedData` and access it one by one

Comment: @Ranjith, he can access any array item directly using dots. See http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

Comment: @Ruslan you are correct. he needs to do something like this `{foreach from=$consolidatedReviewData->consolidatedData key=myId item=i}
  $i.avg_rating
{/foreach}`

Comment: I'd say he needs to construct more convenient data for Smarty. The current array looks ugly to me. I've just answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dots to access array items:

```smarty
{$consolidatedReviews.consolidatedData.0.avg_rating}
```

This is the same as the following in PHP:

```php
echo $consolidatedReviews['consolidatedData'][0]['avg_rating'];
```

`->` is for accessing object properties.

See http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

Comment: @ShekharJoshi, do you have `$consolidatedData[0]`, or `$consolidatedData['avg_rating']` in PHP? Your sample array and "something like..." in the question don't match. Whatever you have, just use dots to access array keys in Smarty

Comment: "something like" is just an example, depicting access to that variable in just one line, instead of looping through the array, I will update. The php array is the correct one.